# How to view REALTIME Laravel/FFMpeg Dispatch Jobs Progress in Laravel 8 with Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, ffmpeg

I use [Laravel-FFMpeg](https://github.com/protonemedia/laravel-ffmpeg) and i try to converting some HLS videos, so I used a Laravel Job to do that.

But I have no idea how to view the **REALTIME** *Progress Info* from dispatched Jobs in my `index.blade.php` with jQuery AJAX.

I've spend days searching for an answer on Google and Youtube, but I found nothing fit.

I use this Job code for `ConvertStreamingVideos`:

```php
FFMpeg::fromDisk('tmp')
    ->open('watermarked/' . $this->video->New_Name . '.mp4')
    ->exportForHLS()
    ->onProgress(function ($percentage, $remaining, $rate) {
        echo "{$percentage}";
    })
    ->addFormat($bitrate_144p)
    ->addFormat($bitrate_240p)
    ->addFormat($bitrate_360p)
    ->addFormat($bitrate_480p)
    ->addFormat($bitrate_720p)
    ->addFormat($bitrate_1080p)
    ->toDisk('public')
    ->save('videos/stream_videos/' . $this->video->New_Name . '.m3u8');
```

Is there any tutorials about it or can someone give me some example codes?

Thanks everyone